# Access my ionic app even screen is locked (Android)

Tags: android, permissions, ionic-framework

I have created an emergency app for users, now i want if the screen is locked (with pattern or password) i want to show some specific details on the screen and user can see that without the need of unlocking phone.(i can ask user permission while installing app, or i can make that permission set as a feature after the installation, from user.)
Please helpout.

I'm doing stuff in Ionic framework.

Thanks !!

Comment: do it through native plugin